# Node JS serverless rest API lambda function that first performs GET request and then POST if condition is met

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I'm new to NodeJS and I'm supposed to write a serverless rest API for a online store (school project). The team I'm in is responsible of the orders customers place. To be able to place the order there has to be enough quantity in inventory (another API), so we need to check quantity in inventory using GET before we store the order in a database using POST. How should we go about this? This is what I  have tried, but I end up getting timeout. The code below is based on this example: [aws-node-rest-api-with-dynamodb](https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-node-rest-api-with-dynamodb-and-offline) for me to get the hang of NodeJS and serverless.

.yml file

```
functions:
  create:
    handler: todos/test.f
    events:
      - http:
          path: todos
          method: post
          cors: true
```

test.js

```
    const create = require("./create.js");
    exports.f = function() {



const https = require('https'); 

https.get('url goes here', (resp) => { 
  let data = ''; 

  // A chunk of data has been recieved. 
  resp.on('data', (chunk) => { 
    data += chunk; 
  }); 

  // The whole response has been received. Print out the result. 
  resp.on('end', () => { 
    console.log(data); 
    var str = String(data);
    console.log("Check: " + (str.trim() == "OK"))
    create.c(); //also tried create.create();

  }); 

}).on("error", (err) => { 
  console.log("Error: " + err.message); 
}); 

      }
```

create.js

```
'use strict';


const uuid = require('uuid');
const dynamodb = require('./dynamodb');

exports.c = function (){
  console.log("Fire!");

}
module.exports.create = (event, context, callback) => {
  const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);
  if (typeof data.text !== 'string') {
    console.error('Validation Failed');
    callback(null, {
      statusCode: 400,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
      body: 'Couldn\'t create the todo item.',
    });
    return;
  }

  const params = {
    TableName: 'todos',
    Item: {
      id: uuid.v1(),
      text: data.text,
      checked: false,
      createdAt: timestamp,
      updatedAt: timestamp,
    },
  };

  // write the todo to the database
  dynamodb.put(params, (error) => {
    // handle potential errors
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      callback(null, {
        statusCode: error.statusCode || 501,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
        body: 'Couldn\'t create the todo item.',
      });
      return;
    }

    // create a response
    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(params.Item),
    };
    callback(null, response);
  });
};
```

Any thoughts on how to get this to work?

Comment: Are you using API gateway? Is that what you're calling with your https.get call? I'm trying to understand because first you seem to call some API, but then you call a local function that does DynamoDB.put...why the first API call then?

Comment: @Deiv I am calling (..or will be)  the inventory teams API to check if there is sufficient quantity of a product(s) and if there is then post the order into the db. The GET request is still incomplete, I just threw something together in order to see if I get both GET and POST to fire.

Comment: Ah okay I see what you mean, you are only responsible for the POST portion but another team will have the GET part you are calling. Do you know what's causing the timeout? Maybe drop a few console.log() calls to figure that out first (unless there is an error, in which case please post it)

Comment: This is the output I get:Serverless: POST /todos (?: create)
OK
Check: true
Fire!
Serverless: Replying timeout after 30000ms

Comment: The code seems to run up until `module.exports.create = (event, context, callback) => {` noticed that I closed the brace after `console.log("Fire!");` so I moved the brace to the end, but it made no difference...

Comment: Have you tried doing just "exports.create" instead of "module.exports.create", and then call create.create(parameters needed)?

Comment: I did, but I don't know what parameters I should use. Using no parameters gives an error and the same goes for using parameters event, context and callback.

Comment: When you call it, you probably don't need the event or context parameters, you can just have the callback, in which case you need to do `exports.create = (callback) => {}` and then call it with `create.create(function(error, success){});`

Comment: Technically, what I would personally do, is use API gateway to create the API for the "create" portion you are responsible for, and have the API gateway trigger a lambda to handle this, in which case it becomes really easy to do.

Comment: Ok, I will look into that. Do you know where I can find information or examples regarding this? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem! [Here's a link for creating an API gateway with Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html), and then for the Lambda portion I recommend you use a code template (they let you pick when you first make the function), play around in the console by running test with random inputs, and then add to it using the [AWS Js SDK, in your case, for DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html)

Comment: [And here's a more detailed example of how to use DynamoDB with Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-table-read-write.html)

Comment: Great stuff thanks a lot! I will start playing around with this to get the hang of it.